# Solving for voltage but getting opposite sign than answer

Tags: voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

So I'm trying to solve a bunch of exercises but I always end up with the opposite sign for the voltage than the correct answer.

The question is to find the voltages of the nodes.

[image: Circuit diagram drawn in LTSpice]

I'm trying to solve it using KCL for each node like this.

\$v_1\$ is the leftmost node above \$R1\$.
\$v_2\$ is the middle node above \$R2\$.
\$v_3\$ is the rightmost node above \$R3\$.

**Equation 1:** KCL for \$v_1\$
\$\frac{v_1}{5\Omega} + \frac{v_1 - v_2}{4\Omega} - 3.5A = 0 \Rightarrow v_1 = \frac{70}{9} V + \frac{5}{9} v_2\$

**Equation 2:** KCL for \$v_2\$
\$3.5A + \frac{v_2 - v_1}{4\Omega} + \frac{v_2}{2.5\Omega} + \frac{v_2 - v_3}{5\Omega} = 0 \Rightarrow 3.5A + \frac{17}{20\Omega} v_2 - \frac{1}{4\Omega} v_1 - \frac{1}{5\Omega} v_3 = 0\$

**Equation 3:** KCL for \$v_3\$
\$2A + \frac{v_3}{10\Omega} + \frac{v_3 - v_2}{5\Omega} = 0 \Rightarrow - \frac{20}{3} V + \frac{2}{3} v_2 = v_3\$

Solving for \$v_2\$ by plugging in equation 1 and 3 into equation 2 like this
\$3.5A + \frac{17}{20\Omega} v_2 - \frac{1}{4\Omega} (\frac{70}{9} V + \frac{5}{9} v_2) - \frac{1}{5\Omega} (- \frac{20}{3} V + \frac{2}{3} v_2) = 0 \Rightarrow v_2 = -5V\$

The answer according to the circuit simulator is \$5V\$. The book confirms that \$5V\$ is the correct answer for \$v_2\$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sum of currents away from a node = 0; e.g. Eqn 1 should be +3.5

Comment: You shouldn't put units in equations - it's really confusing. So omit the \$\small A\$, \$\small V\$, \$\small \Omega\$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chu's comment is the right tip.
To answer what you're doing wrong in a more general sense:
You only have the direction of the current sources reversed compared to your calcuated (Voltage/Resistance) currents.

Starting with Eqn 1, v1/5 is current flowing *from* v1 to ground.  The 3.5A current source is also moving away from v1.  So, if you're going to list all the current sources coming from v1, they should be the same sign (+) and have them added together (v1/5 + 3.5 + (v1-v2)/4).

Similarly for Eqn 2 & 3, you just have the sign/polarity of the current sources inconsistent with your V/R currents.  So, -3.5A in Eqn2, and -2A in Eqn3.

Your consistent reversal of the current sources would explain your consistency in getting negative versions of the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to list out-going currents on the left and incoming currents on the right. It helps me mentally "book-keep" more easily:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1}{R_5}+3.5\:\textrm{A}&=\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_5}\\\\
\therefore 0 &=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{R_5}+3.5\:\textrm{A}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_2}{R_4}+\frac{V_2}{R_5}&=3.5\:\textrm{A}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}+\frac{V_1}{R_5}\\\\
\therefore 0 &=\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_2-V_3}{R_4}+\frac{V_2-V_1}{R_5}-3.5\:\textrm{A}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}&=2\:\textrm{A}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_3}+\frac{V_2}{R_4}\\\\
\therefore 0 &=\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_3-V_2}{R_4}-2\:\textrm{A}
\end{align*}$$

From the above, you can see several errors you made related to the current sources.

This solves out as: \$V_1=-5\:\textrm{V}\$, \$V_2=5\:\textrm{V}\$, \$V_3=10\:\textrm{V}\$.